# Check 2 lists of 3D coordinates intersection in a performant way

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

I have the following use case:
I have 1 million 3D objects. I want to check which elements "intersect". For that, I first used voxelization, which transforms the 3D objects into a cloud of 3D coordinates.
I now want to "intersect" these clouds, and for each 2 elements that have are not "disjoint", I'll consider to intersect.

The intersection takes a long time. What I do today for the intersection is as follows:

1. Each voxel is turned into bytes (numpy.tobytes()), and I create a set for the voxel cloud per element -> {x.tobytes() for x in element.voxel_cloud} [this part is not as quick as I'd hope, but not the real issue]
2. I already have the bounding box xyz of the elements, so I create lists of "candidates" - for each element, the list of elements whose 3D bounding box intersect [this part is very quick]
3. For each couple that needs "intersection test", I do:
   element_1.voxel_set.isdisjoint(element_2.voxel_set)

The third part is slow [not slow per element, but slow since I have millions of intersections to test]
Also, loading the voxels of all the elements into the memory is problematic (as it's huge). The main issue is that each set can be as large as 100K to millions of "voxel indexes". Each "voxel" is represented as 3 int32 numbers, converted to bytes.

I'd appreciate ideas as to how more quickly test the disjointness.
Things I thought about that I don't use today:

1. I could preprocess the voxels further. I could sort them, I could compress them further (my 3D space doesn't really need 3 int32 coordinates to be represented)
2. maybe using sets is not smart enough (I tried using KD Trees, but it was much slower)

I'm using Python 3.10, my voxels are a numpy area (before being converted to bytes)

Comment: Please note that regarding the complexity initial geometry, using voxels can actually make things slower. Set intersection is AFAIK O(n) but the memory indirections can make things really slow if the amount of data is huge. What about using simply a *bitmap* ? It is compact (assuming the voxel clouds are compact area), and cache efficient. Regarding the actual data, grid-partitioning and kd-tree may help indeed. The thing is this is hard to help you without knowing what the code and data actually look like. Details matters a lot when it comes to performance.